# Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.4) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm simply trying to start a local composer server at my machine but I'm facing the following error :

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.4) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)
```

However, my composer version looks perfectly fine -->

```
    npm list -g --depth=0
/home/paris/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib
├── @ampretia/composer-wallet-cloudant@0.2.1
├── composer-cli@0.20.0
├── composer-rest-server@0.20.0
├── composer-runtime@0.20.0
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.19.5
├── loopback-connector-mongodb@3.6.0
├── npm@5.6.0
├── passport-github@1.1.0
└── yo@2.0.5
```

I already cleaned the images and etc...

Answer (score 3):

The `composer-runtime` doesn't run client side, it is part of your business network running inside your fabric network. It looks like you have installed `composer-runtime` manually otherwise it would not be seen client side.

When you deployed your business network you used composer-cli at 0.19.4. Now you have upgraded to composer 0.20.0. The rule for compatibility is as follows
composer_client version must be >= composer_runtime version and the minor version MUST be equal (minor version is the middle number). For example

[image: Example Table]

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server and I having trouble after running docker run. It throws the same error, knowing that when I run only composer-rest-server it works perfectly and my composer-client is 19.14 just like my runtime so I don't see why the error is still appearing

Comment: If you are pulling a docker image down, make sure you specify the exact version, if you are pulling latest down then you will be pulling down 0.20.0 and the rest server is a client side application so conforms to the above rules